# Call to undefined method Google_Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()

Tags: php, gmail-api

Hello im having this problem. Im working with google Gmail Api. I did every thing on my own server it is working fine. I uploaded to another one but i get this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google_Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode(). Here is my function

```
<?php
  require __DIR__ .'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
  use Google_Client as GoogleClient;

  public function getClient()
  {
    $client = new GoogleClient();//Call the google client
    $client->setApplicationName($this->projectName);//Set project name
    $client->setScopes(
        [
            'https://mail.google.com/',
        ]
    );//Set Scopes
    $client->setAuthConfig($this->jsonKeyFilePath);//Set Application credentials get from Google console developers
    $client->setRedirectUri($this->redirectUri);//Set redirect Url
    $client->setAccessType('offline');//Set offline mode to get refresh token. Usefull for cron task
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');//Force Api to return Refresh token as sometimes it may not return

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    if (file_exists($this->tokenFile)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->tokenFile), true);
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        //Check the unique code returned by Google Auth
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $authCode = $_GET['code'];
            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($this->redirectUri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            //Create file where token will be stored if not exist
            if(!file_exists(dirname($this->tokenFile))) {
                mkdir(dirname($this->tokenFile), 0700, true);
            }
            //Save returned tokens to file for next operations on behalf of user
            file_put_contents($this->tokenFile, json_encode($accessToken));
        }else{
            //If google didnt return the auth code
            exit('No code found');
        }
    }
    //Set the token
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

        // save refresh token to some variable
        $refreshTokenSaved = $client->getRefreshToken();

        // update access token
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenSaved);

        // pass access token to some variable
        $accessTokenUpdated = $client->getAccessToken();

        // append refresh token
        $accessTokenUpdated['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;

        // save to file
        file_put_contents($this->tokenFile, json_encode($accessTokenUpdated));
    }
    return $client;//return client
}
```

Comment: You could show your GoogleClient so we could help you with debugging, this looks good to me.

Comment: I made an update

Comment: Realy need help guys

Comment: Make sure that you've followed the steps in this [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) and this [sample code](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php). Be noted that if you have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow, you need to exchange that with the `Google_Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()` function.

Comment: Is fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode a static method ? I follow the steps an on my dev server it xas working fine. On my prod server it is now working no more

Comment: `fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()` has been added in version 1.1.16, what version do you run in production?

Comment: Ive found. In the wordpress installation there was a plugin using an older version of the library. So when i disable that plugin everything works perfect. I wonder if there is a way to use both version

Comment: I was running into a similar problem, and it was because i had multiple Google_Client.php files. ensure you have only the correct 1 and test again.

Answer (score 1):

> fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode() has been added in version 1.1.16, what version do you run in production? – Dygnus Apr 21 '17 at 21:28

After you've checked your version.

You could also try it with:

```
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
```

A similar problem is also mentioned here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1204.